# Cocoapods: add a new pod without replacing existing old one

Tags: cocoapods

I have a project that I added alamofire before but now when I want to add another I saw is it replacing new one with alamofire how should I avoid this?

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'WeatherApp' do 
  pod 'TextFieldEffects',
  :git => 'https://github.com/raulriera/TextFieldEffects.git'
end
```

and result is

> removing alamofire and install TextFieldEffects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, “9.0”
use_frameworks!

target 'WeatherApp' do
pod 'TextFieldEffects', :git =>'https://github.com/raulriera/TextFieldEffects.git' 
pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git'
end
```

Or even this should work:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'WeatherApp' do
  pod 'TextFieldEffects'
  pod 'Alamofire'
end
```